# Hive - Why does Hive add a row to COLUMNS_V2 table in Meta-store every time we add partition to an external table?

Tags: hive

A query like Select COLUMN_NAME, count(1) from COLUMNS_V2 group by COLUMN_NAME showed external table columns with count equal to the number of partitions added.

Comment: I think it is being used for column statistics (partition level) but I have to dig deeper!